# openid login yahoo

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid

I am trying to let users to login with yahoo OpenId in to my application using this [code](http://code.google.com/p/apps-marketplace-resources/source/browse/trunk/helloworld-java/src/main/java/com/google/code/samples/apps/marketplace/OpenIdServlet.java?r=13).

I tried connecting to "yahoo.com" for open id which failed to process the request, I changed it to "me.yahoo.com" it worked fine.

But now I figured out that the request is actually failing, resulting an exception saying "verification failed for http://me.yahoo.com/a/{id}.."

To my surprise, the same code works fine with the other application I hosted. Is there anything related to IP/ Geographic specification problems which raises an exception while openid url verification? Which bothers me more is, the error is not raised consistently, it works fine sometimes.